# cgroup versus cgroups in tagging

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Our current tag for this concept is [cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgroups).

However, according to [the official kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#terminology):

> “cgroup” stands for “control group” and is never capitalized. The singular form is used to designate the whole feature and also as a qualifier as in “cgroup controllers”. When explicitly referring to multiple individual control groups, the plural form “cgroups” is used.

Since this is explicitly mentioned in the official documentation, I think it would be good to retag [cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgroups) questions to [cgroup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgroup) and add a synonym so future uses of [cgroups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgroups) auto-correct to [cgroup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cgroup).

I know you can't legislate language usage, but it would be good to have our tag usage correspond to the official documentation (in my opinion).

Responses?

Comment: Related is cgroup v1 versus cgroup v2, which will become important in time as cgroup v1 advice won't work with cgroup v2.  For now I've updated the tag wiki to alert people to the difference.